# I know 3 sides of a triangle and I'm trying to find the angles

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, quadratic-forms

> A triangle has one side with the length of $7cm$, another side with the length of $5cm$, and another side with the length of $9cm$. I need to find the angles of the triangle but I don't know where to start, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Law of cosines?

Comment: [Cosine rule](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/furthertrigonometryhirev2.shtml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply the cosine rule, which states that:
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos A$$

Just substitute the lengths of the three sides into the equation to find the angles. Remember that if you let $a=7$, you will be finding the angle opposite the side of length $7$